# PWA - Manifest doesn't have a maskable icon issue

Tags: javascript, json, progressive-web-apps

I am learning to build a PWA. I am currently working on an extremely beginner stuff. I successfully completed all the basic and required steps to make my webpage a compatible PWA. But i am getting 'Manifest doesn't have a maskable icon issue' again and again and not able to understand how to solve it. Attaching a screenshot of the issue below.

[image: Click to enlarge]

It would be great if I can get some help on this.

tried building the project over again but that didn't work.

Comment: check out https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/pwa/maskable-icon-audit/

Comment: Please include the code for your manifest.json file in the question.

Comment: @mmh4all thanks alot, the documentation was helpful